# What is an epoch when using keras generators?

Tags: python, generator, keras

I want to use fit_generator to handle my data.

I understand the generator must be running forever, and that samples_per_epoch defines the number of elements yielded from the generator before getting to the next epoch.

But what is an epoch here ? When we run fit, an epoch is a run against the whole data set, split according to batch_size. But here, batch_size has no meaning since fit_generator works like calling train_on_batch on each element of the generator, and there is no such thing as "the whole dataset".

My question is: do samples_per_epoch and nb_epoch have a meaning? Or in any case the network is trained the same way on samples_per_epoch*nb_epoch batches returned by the generator, and the epoch has no real meaning?

Answer (score 3):

`fit_generator` is blind to what data is produced by the generator. Its the responsibility of the generator class to go over the whole dataset. Using `samples_per_epoch` the `fit_generator` simply keeps track of the epoch count. Check [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1473-L1477) & [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1532-LL1541) & [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1565).

Comment: Ok so the only thing that determine the training is samples_per_epoch*nb_epoch? The rest is just for printing?

Comment: Your second link is interesting, so in fact I was wrong, samples_per_epoch*nb_epoch is not the number of batches, but the sum of the sizes of the different batches.

Comment: Ya you can set the samples_per_epoch as the total training size and split and pass it however you want by the generator. But I usually round it off by the batch size.. making the generator threads easier to implement. You can check one one my answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633087/how-to-use-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-a-siamese-or-tripple-networks/41645732#41645732